# How do I include files in DrScheme?

Tags: racket, sicp

I'm using DrScheme to work through SICP, and I've noticed that certain procedures (for example, `square`) get used over and over.  I'd like to put these in a separate file so that I can include them in other programs without having to rewrite them every time, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I've tried:

```
(load filename)
(load (filename))
(load ~/path-to-directory/filename)
(require filename)
(require ~/path-to-directory/filename)
(require path-from-root/filename)
```

None of these works.  Obviously I'm grasping at straws -- any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear from your question what language level you're using; certain legacy languages may make certain mechanisms unavailable.

The best inclusion/abstraction mechanism is that of modules.

First, set your language level to "module". Then, if I have these two files in the same directory:

File uses-square.ss:

```
#lang scheme

(require "square.ss")

(define (super-duper x) (square (square x)))
```

File square.ss :

```
#lang scheme

(provide square)

(define (square x) (* x x))
```

Then I can hit "run" on the "uses-square.ss" buffer and everything will work the way you'd expect.

Caveat: untested code.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for:

```
(include "relative/path/to/scheme/file.scm")
```

The (require) expression is for loading modules.

Answer (score 1):

In MIT/GNU Scheme, you can load a file with something like this:

```
(load "c:\\sample-directory\\sample-file.scm")
```

But I do not know if it works in DrScheme.

Comment: it works in DrScheme if the language is set to SIPC, using the SICP add-in

Answer (score 1):

```
(require "~/path-to-directory/filename")
```