# How to load file from dir using Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to set a dir to load files from using racket. I want to set the dir and then use command `(load "extract.rktl")` to load the file.

I'm on windows environment.

Command I'm trying is :

```
(add-to-list 'load-path ("c:/Users/racket/")
```

I receive error :

```
add-to-list: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier
  context...:
```

the dir c:\Users\racket exists. Are commands correct ?

Update : this helped : [How do I include files in DrScheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207648/how-do-i-include-files-in-drscheme)

Comment: The error is stating that the procedure `add-to-list` is undefined, _not_ that the directory doesn't exist

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: you say it better ;p

Answer (score 1):

In Racket, `path` is a type and strings are not paths. So convert the name of a path with `string->path`.

```
(define default-dir
  (string->path "c:\\user\\racket"))
```

Notes:

- The Windows separator character '\' must be escaped as '\'.
- Many Racket functions that act on paths will implicitly convert strings to paths without an explicit call to `string->path`.
- However string operations cannot be permed on path objects.

> ```
> >(string-split default-dir "\\")
> string-split: contract violation
> expected: string?
> given: #<path:c:\user\racket>
> ```

Alternatively, a GUI can be used:

```
> (require racket/gui)
> (define my-file (get-file))
> my-file
#<path:/home/ben/Documents/racket/my-module.rkt>
```

Comment: Most Racket functions that deal with paths also accept strings and automatically convert them to paths. The problem isn't the path; it's the function (see the comment by Óscar López).

Comment: @RyanCulpepper I didn't address the syntax error because that pain point is much more fleeting than trying to tease standard file operations out of the Racket documentation - `2htdp/batch-io` is buried below the top level of documentation and it's the only beginner friendly treatment of reading and writing files in the docs.